# Create test account using EOSIO

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio-code, rpc

I am new with EOSIO.

I have created account using cleos command.

```
cleos create account eosio bob YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY 
cleos create account eosio alice YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY
```

It's successfully created. But, I wanted to create account using RPC API. So, I tried to find out "create account" API in API document, but there is not available. So, Is there any way to create account using http request?

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to create account in public network?

Comment: Yes. I am implementing functions using C++.

Answer (score 2):

There is no RPC api for create account. But you can implement it using `push_transaction` api. In eos, only an existing account can create a new account. 
You can create a new account by pushing some transactions defined in `eosio.system` contract from an existing account. `eosio.system` contract is deployed in `eosio` account. So for creating a new account, you should have,

- An existing account with required RAM and BW
- Public key of the account to be created
- New account name

Go to `eosio.system` contract. You can find these actions

- newaccount
- buyrambytes
- delegatebw

Push these actions by passing required parameters from your existing account using [push_transaction](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transactions-1https://) api

eosio.system contract can be found [here](https://github.com/Muhzn/eos-1/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.cpp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Let me try.